# Plotting multi-colored line in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to plot a vertical line (I'd prefer any orientation, but I'd be happy with just vertical right now) with two-color dashes, say red-blue-red-blue-...

I know I could do it like this:

```
plot([1,1],[0,1],'r'),
hold on,
plot([1,1],[0,1],'--b')
```

However, since I need to be able to move the line, among others, it should only have a single handle. How could I do this?

**EDIT**
Thank you for your answers. I guess I should indeed give some more information.

I have some data that is classified into different parts. I want to be able to manually adjust the boundaries between classes. For this, I'm drawing vertical lines at the classification boundaries and use [draggable](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4179-draggable) to allow moving the lines.

For the boundary between the red and the blue class, I'd like to have a red/blue line.

```
plot(ones(10,1),linspace(0,1,10),'-bs','MarkerFaceColor','r','MarkerEdgeColor','none','linewidth',6)
```

is what I'm actually using at the moment. However, it's not so pretty (if I want equal spacing, it becomes a real pain, and I want to give both colors the same weight), and I would like to have the possibility to use three colors (and not with marker edge and face being different, because it makes my eyes bleed).

Unfortunately, draggable does not allow me to use multiple handles, and grouping the lines with hggroup does not seem to create a draggable object.

[cline](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14677-cline) looks like a promising approach, but rainbow colors won't work for my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the code you have, and just concatenate the handles from each line into a vector of handles. When you want to change the properties of both lines simultaneously, the [SET](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/set.html) function is able to accept the vector of handles as an argument. From the documentation for [SET](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/set.html):

> `set(H,'PropertyName',PropertyValue,...)`
>   sets the named properties to the
>   specified values on the object(s)
>   identified by `H`. `H` can be a vector of
>   handles, in which case `set` sets the
>   properties' values for all the
>   objects.

Here's an example:

```
h1 = plot([1 1],[0 1],'r');    %# Plot line 1
hold on;
h2 = plot([1 1],[0 1],'--b');  %# Plot line 2
hVector = [h1 h2];             %# Vector of handles
set(hVector,'XData',[2 3]);    %# Shifts the x data points for both lines
```

---

**UPDATE:** Since you mention you are using [draggable](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4179-draggable) from the [MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/), here's an alternate solution. From the description of [draggable](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4179-draggable):

> A function which is called when the
>   object is moved can be provided as an
>   optional argument, so that the
>   movement triggers further actions.

You could then try the following solution:

- Plot your two lines, saving the handle for each (i.e. `h1` and `h2`).
- Put the handle for each in the `'UserData'` property of the other:

  ```
  set(h1,'UserData',h2);
  set(h2,'UserData',h1);
  ```
- Create the following function:

  ```
  function motionFcn(hMoving)  %# Currently moving handle is passed in
    hOther = get(hMoving,'UserData');  %# Get the other plot handle
    set(hOther,'XData',get(hMoving,'XData'),...  %# Update the x data
               'YData',get(hMoving,'YData'));    %# Update the y data
  end
  ```
- Turn on [draggable](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4179-draggable) for both lines, using the above function as the one called when either object is moved:

  ```
  draggable(h1,@motionFcn);
  draggable(h2,@motionFcn);
  ```

Comment: Yes, I'd like to be able to do that. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work for my application (see edit).

Comment: @Jonas: I added an additional solution to my answer that I think should work with draggable.

Comment: Thanks! This works very nicely. I need to use setappdata/getappdata, because I already use UserData, though.

Comment: @Jonas: Glad it worked for you. Incidentally, I couldn't actually test the solution because draggable doesn't seem to work with my version of MATLAB (7.8.0 R2009a). Maybe something in the newer versions breaks it, seeing as how it was written for version 6.5 (R13).

Comment: @gnovice: draggable works fine for me with 2009a on OS X. However, you  cannot drag the line outside the axes boundaries, so you should plot either a horizontal or vertical, not a diagonal line. :)

Comment: @Jonas: Yeah, that was the problem. I didn't notice you had switched the example in the question to a vertical line. Works fine now! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've never used it, but there's a submission by Sebastian Hölz called [CLINE](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14677-cline) on the Mathworks File Exchange that seems related.

Comment: That's almost what I need. At any rate, it's nice to know that cline exists.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do exactly what you want, but presumably the reason you want to do this is to have some way of distinguishing this line from other lines. Along those lines, take a look at MathWorks' [documentation on 2-D line plots](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html). Specifically, this example:

```
plot(x,y,'--rs','LineWidth',2,...
                'MarkerEdgeColor','k',...
                'MarkerFaceColor','g',...
                'MarkerSize',10)
```

should give you plenty of ideas for variation. If you really need the two-color dashes, it might help to specify why. That way, even if we can't answer the question, perhaps we can convince you that you don't really need the two-color dashes. Since you've already ruled out the over-lapping solution, I'm fairly certain there's no solution that answers all of your needs. I'm assuming the two-colorness is the most fluid of those needs.

Comment: As it turns out, I have actually read the manual first (though I admit I should have mentioned that), and I do really want the two-colorness.