# How to plot function with different color for different interval?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a typical scenario in which there is a Vector **X** and Vector **Y**. Vector X contains increasing values, for example X = [1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4]. Vector Y contains real values of same size as X. Im looking to plot **Index Vs Y** with color change for each different value of X for the corresponding index.

For example, the plot should have color1 for the first 3 values of 1, color2 for the next 2 values of 2, color3 for 1 value 3 and so on.

Can any one help me

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2444575/plotting-multi-colored-line-in-matlab, it has several suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on [Laurent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709521/how-to-plot-function-with-different-color-for-different-interval/7709714#7709714) and implementing your "**Index vs Y**" requirement,

```
function color_plot(data_vector, color_vector)
styles={'ro','g.','bx','kd'};
hold off;
for i=unique(color_vector)
    thisIdx=find(color_vector==i);
    thisY=data_vector(color_vector==i);
    thisStyle=styles{mod(i-1,numel(styles))+1}; 
    plot(thisIdx,thisY,thisStyle);
    hold on;
end
hold off;
```

My version also allows arbitrarily large color indices; if you don't have enough styles defined, it just wraps back around and reuses colors.

**Update** note I had to fix a sign above in the calculation oh `thisStyle`.

Testing it with

```
X = [1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 4 4];
Y=rand(size(X))
color_plot(Y,X)
```

now gives

[image]

Comment: I like your code (it's much more compact than mine!). It shows some gaps between the segments when used with lines though (i.e. 'r-' style).

Comment: True - my code doesn't try to join the separate segments... it wouldn't be as compact if it did ;-).

Answer (score 3):

A `plot()` function option would be better (and maybe it exists).

Here's a workaround function to do this:

```
function colorPlot( data_vector, colors_vector)
%PLOTCOL plots data_vector with colors found in colors_vector

Styles=[{'r-'} {'g-'} {'b-'} {'k-'}];


last_off=0;
last_data=0;
for i=unique(colors_vector)
    data_segment=data_vector(colors_vector==i);
    len=length(data_segment);
    if last_off==0
        hold off;
        plot( data_segment, 1:len,char(Styles(i)));
        last_off=len;
    else
        plot([last_data data_segment],last_off:last_off+len,char(Styles(i)));
        last_off=last_off+len;
    end
    last_data=data_segment(len);
    hold on;
end
hold off;
end
```

Call it this way :

```
colorPlot(Y,X);
```

Comment: Fixed some bugs in this version (color segments are now continuous, finally plots value vs indexes)

Comment: Hmm... when someone says "plot `a` vs `Y`", for you `a` is on the y axis and `Y` on the x axis? I understand it the other way round...

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg "plot `a` vs. `Y`", actually yes, I assume `a` is the ordinate and `Y` the absissa. (But I'm not a native speaker, maybe I'm wrong)

Comment: I'm no native speaker either. Let's wait and see if @Learner tells us what he wanted :-). In any case it is important to note that **our two solutions have x and y interchanged**...

Comment: @JonasHeidelberg Well, i was looking for simple logic to plot the value. I dont mind x vs y or y vs x. Thanks for both the answers.